# Efficient online linear regression algorithm in python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I got a 2-D dataset with two columns `x` and `y`. I would like to get the linear regression coefficients and interception dynamically when new data feed in. Using scikit-learn I could calculate all current available data like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regr = LinearRegression()
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(100)+10*np.random.random_sample((100,))
regr.fit(x,y)
print(regr.coef_)
print(regr.intercept_)
```

However, I got quite big dataset (more than 10k rows in total) and I want to calculate coefficient and intercept as fast as possible whenever there's new rows coming in. Currently calculate 10k rows takes about 600 microseconds, and I want to accelerate this process.

Scikit-learn looks like does not have online update function for linear regression module. Is there any better ways to do this?

Comment: In sklearn, only estimators [noted here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) have the capability of online learning.

Comment: @VivekKumar Is there any other formula or package can solve this?

Comment: sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor is Linear regression, but instead of using least squares method, its using Gradient decent. You should give it a try and see if your output remains close enough (or at least the "loss" is the same), plus SGD (Stochastic Gradient Decent) is much faster on big data sets with big dimensions of features. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found solution from this paper: [updating simple linear regression](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24305577). The implementation is as below:

```
def lr(x_avg,y_avg,Sxy,Sx,n,new_x,new_y):
    """
    x_avg: average of previous x, if no previous sample, set to 0
    y_avg: average of previous y, if no previous sample, set to 0
    Sxy: covariance of previous x and y, if no previous sample, set to 0
    Sx: variance of previous x, if no previous sample, set to 0
    n: number of previous samples
    new_x: new incoming 1-D numpy array x
    new_y: new incoming 1-D numpy array x
    """
    new_n = n + len(new_x)

    new_x_avg = (x_avg*n + np.sum(new_x))/new_n
    new_y_avg = (y_avg*n + np.sum(new_y))/new_n

    if n > 0:
        x_star = (x_avg*np.sqrt(n) + new_x_avg*np.sqrt(new_n))/(np.sqrt(n)+np.sqrt(new_n))
        y_star = (y_avg*np.sqrt(n) + new_y_avg*np.sqrt(new_n))/(np.sqrt(n)+np.sqrt(new_n))
    elif n == 0:
        x_star = new_x_avg
        y_star = new_y_avg
    else:
        raise ValueError

    new_Sx = Sx + np.sum((new_x-x_star)**2)
    new_Sxy = Sxy + np.sum((new_x-x_star).reshape(-1) * (new_y-y_star).reshape(-1))

    beta = new_Sxy/new_Sx
    alpha = new_y_avg - beta * new_x_avg
    return new_Sxy, new_Sx, new_n, alpha, beta, new_x_avg, new_y_avg
```

Performance comparison:

Scikit learn version that calculate 10k samples altogether.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
x = np.arange(10000).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.arange(10000)+100*np.random.random_sample((10000,))
regr = LinearRegression()
%timeit regr.fit(x,y)
# 419 µs ± 14.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

My version assume 9k sample is already calculated:

```
Sxy, Sx, n, alpha, beta, new_x_avg, new_y_avg = lr(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x.reshape(-1,1)[:9000], y[:9000])
new_x, new_y = x.reshape(-1,1)[9000:], y[9000:]
%timeit lr(new_x_avg, new_y_avg, Sxy,Sx,n,new_x, new_y)
# 38.7 µs ± 1.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

10 times faster, which is expected.

Comment: Do you get similar predictions/ coefficients comparing to sklearn?

Comment: @VivekKumar they coefficient and intercept are the same

Comment: Sxy is really n times the covariance, and Sx is really n times the variance of x, is it not?

Answer (score 2):

I've adapted Kevin Fang's answer into a class:

```
import numpy as np

class OnlineLinearRegression:
    """
    Online linear regression in O(1) mem & compute
    """
    def __init__(self):
        # Average of all x seen
        self.x_avg = 0.
        # Average of all y seen
        self.y_avg = 0.
        # Covariance of all x and y seen
        self.xy_covar = 0.
        # Variance of all x seen
        self.x_var = 0.
        # Number of observations seen
        self.n = 0

    @property
    def parameters(self):
        """
        :return: the parameters of the linear regression (beta, alpha) such that y = beta * x + alpha. If there are
        less than 2 observations, returns (None, None).
        """
        if self.n < 2:
            return None, None
        else:
            beta = self.xy_covar / self.x_var
            alpha = self.y_avg - beta * self.x_avg
            return beta, alpha

    def update_multiple(self, new_x: np.ndarray, new_y: np.ndarray):
        assert len(new_x) == len(new_y)
        new_n = self.n + len(new_x)

        new_x_avg = (self.x_avg * self.n + np.sum(new_x)) / new_n
        new_y_avg = (self.y_avg * self.n + np.sum(new_y)) / new_n

        if self.n:
            x_star = (self.x_avg * np.sqrt(self.n) + new_x_avg * np.sqrt(new_n)) / (np.sqrt(self.n) + np.sqrt(new_n))
            y_star = (self.y_avg * np.sqrt(self.n) + new_y_avg * np.sqrt(new_n)) / (np.sqrt(self.n) + np.sqrt(new_n))
        else:
            x_star = new_x_avg
            y_star = new_y_avg

        self.n = new_n
        self.x_avg = new_x_avg
        self.y_avg = new_y_avg

        self.x_var = self.x_var + np.sum((new_x - x_star) ** 2)
        self.xy_covar = self.xy_covar + np.sum((new_x - x_star).reshape(-1) * (new_y - y_star).reshape(-1))

    def update(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.update_multiple(np.array([x]), np.array([y]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice! Thanks for sharing your findings :) Here is an equivalent implementation of this solution written with dot products:

```py
class SimpleLinearRegressor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dots = np.zeros(5)
        self.intercept = None
        self.slope = None

    def update(self, x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray):
        self.dots += np.array(
            [
                x.shape[0],
                x.sum(),
                y.sum(),
                np.dot(x, x),
                np.dot(x, y),
            ]
        )
        size, sum_x, sum_y, sum_xx, sum_xy = self.dots
        det = size * sum_xx - sum_x ** 2
        if det > 1e-10:  # determinant may be zero initially
            self.intercept = (sum_xx * sum_y - sum_xy * sum_x) / det
            self.slope = (sum_xy * size - sum_x * sum_y) / det
```

When working with time series data, we can extend this idea to do [sliding window regression](https://scaron.info/blog/simple-linear-regression-with-online-updates.html#sliding-window-simple-linear-regression) with a soft ([EMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average)-like) window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use accelerated libraries that implement faster algorithms - particularly
https://github.com/intel/scikit-learn-intelex

For linear regression you would get much better performance

First install package

```sh
pip install scikit-learn-intelex
```

And then add in your python script

```py
from sklearnex import patch_sklearn
patch_sklearn()
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31012763)